# What does this structure mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to learn Chef but I'm having some difficulties understanding what this Ruby code does.

```
web_app "helloworld" do
  server_name "hello.world"
  server_aliases ["www.hello.world"]
  docroot "/var/www/helloworld"
end
```

From what I understand, the first line calls `web_app` with the argument `"helloworld"` but I don't get what the `do` stands for in this context, does `web_app` return a list? When I see a list iterator in Ruby the value is passed like this `do |v|`. I'm guessing it's not iterating as it would make little sense to execute that code multiple times.

Comment: the code inside the `do` and `end` keywords is called a *block* in Ruby. here, you're calling the `web_app` method with `"helloworld"` and a block as arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`do` and `end` encapsulate a [block in ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/). you may pass a block to every method call if you wish. [It is up to the method what to do with the block](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_m_kernel.html#Kernel.block_given_qm).

Most methods don't care about attached blocks, but the [`web_app` method seems to call the block to configure itself](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2#web_app).

If you want to dive into that, here are some pointers:

- [the place where `web_app` is defined](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2/blob/452e446841353de1f0da00c37cff8c5e95c41da3/definitions/web_app.rb#L20)
- [the place where the block is taken from `define`](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/1bb1a934fe397874b86ec00d6aff2df7b3eb6017/lib/chef/resource_definition.rb#L37)